# Проблема с DIFFERENCE функцией

Tags: sql, sql-server

Существует массив городов из 499 сущностей, из которых 486 c уникальным именем. Функция DIFFERENCE дает не совсем ожидаемый результат:

```
SELECT COUNT(CITY) AS N1, COUNT(DISTINCT CITY) AS N2, DIFFERENCE('N1', 'N2') FROM STATION
```

Результат

```
499 486 4
```

Но должно выдавать результат 13. Как я понимаю, сравнение идет не числа, а типа. Подскажите пожалуйста, как сравнить именно числа из выборки? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вам эта функция не поможет, она сравнивает строки.

Попробуйте так:
`SELECT ABS (COUNT(City) - COUNT(DISTINCT City)) [Difference]  FROM STATION`
 получите разницу между числами по модулю.

Подробнее: [DIFFERENCE](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/functions/difference-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), [ABS](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/functions/abs-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)